# FIlter rows from right outer join

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which has a right outer join in which i need to pick the latest update rows from left table based on the attribute last_update_date. Without the additional criteria of taking latest row based on last_update_date the query is working fine.When I add the additional Where clause that left

```
table.last_update_date = Select max(last_update_date) 
                         from left_table2 
                         where left_table_join_id = right_table_join_id
```

, the whole resultset vanishes and i dont have any results anymore.Please help

Comment: give example of your input, the code used and the output. Its much easier for us to understand that way. Look at other questions on SQL to understand how to display the examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` in your upstream step.